# Remove the last column of dataframe in R in a function

Tags: r, loops, drop

I need to remove the last column of 10 dataframes, so I decided to put it in lapply(). I wrote a function to remove the col, like below,

```
remove_col <- function(mydata){
  mydata = subset(mydata, select=-c(24))
}
```

and create a `mylist <- (data1, data2.... data10)`, then I passed lapply as

```
lapply(mylist, FUN = remove_col)
```

It did give me a list of the removed dataframe, however, when I checked the original dataframe, the last column is still there.
How should I change the code to change the original dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the function call to the input list on the LHS:

```
mylist <- lapply(mylist, FUN = remove_col)
```

Had you defined your function with an explicit return value, this might have been more obvious:

```
remove_col <- function(mydata) {
    mydata <- subset(mydata, select=-c(24))
    return(mydata)   # return the modified list/data frame
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the column number to remove you can use `ncol` to remove the last column from each dataframe.

```
remove_col <- function(mydata){
  mydata[, -ncol(mydata)]
}
mylist <- lapply(mylist, remove_col)
```

To see the changes in the original dataframe you can assign names to list of dataframe and use `list2env`.

```
names(mylist) <- paste0('data', seq_along(mylist))
list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R and lapply, Note, you can remove ", drop = F" from your script if there are more than 2 columns in all dataframes in the list.

```
> d1
  c1 c2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10
> d2
  c1 c2
1  5 10
2  4  9
3  3  8
4  2  7
5  1  6
> mylist <- list(d1, d2)
> mylist
[[1]]
  c1 c2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10

[[2]]
  c1 c2
1  5 10
2  4  9
3  3  8
4  2  7
5  1  6

> lapply(mylist, function(x) x[,1:(ncol(x)-1), drop = F] )
[[1]]
  c1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5

[[2]]
  c1
1  5
2  4
3  3
4  2
5  1

>
```